# netbeans c++ change remote building path

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, netbeans-8

I'm using Netbeans 8.2 on a Win 10 Machine for remote developing on a RaspPi with Raspbian Jessi.

I set up the remote building system and it works very well.

There one think I do not like. Netbeans is using this path to copy the data

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/.netbeans/remote/192.168.1.46/workstation-Windows-x86_64/C/Users/user/Documents/NetBeansProjects/.....
```

How can I change this path e.g. to

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/NetBeansProjects/
```

Comment: Are you connecting to a remote build host, or using a remote project? If the latter, which file access mechanism are you using?

Comment: Well, the files access works with sftp and I'm using a build host.